# Spark Scala, write data with SaveMode.Append while overwriting some existing partition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hive

I have the following command, in my spark program

```
df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("year","month","day")
  .format(format)
  .option("path",path)
  .saveAsTable(table_name)
```

When I run it twice on the same date, I have duplicates in my data. So i want it to append the data but when some partitions already exist, it should overwrite them.

Comment: what version of spark are u using ?

Comment: am using spark 2.3.0

Comment: Was a little too hasty, cheers, it's there now with a complete worked example.

Comment: This is how it works.

Comment: Did you manage to find the better way? If so, pls post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in 2 steps:

1. add the following spark conf,
   sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
2. I used the following function to deal with the cases where I should overwrite or just append.

first import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

```
def writePartitionOverriding(df: DataFrame, tableName: String, path: String, spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
  val fullPath = path + partition

  if (FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(fullPath)))
     dfToWrite.write
              .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
              .format("orc")
              .partitionBy("year","month","day")
              .save(path)
  else
     writePartitionBySaveAsTable(dfToWrite, tableName, path, partition)
}

def writePartitionBySaveAsTable(df: DataFrame, tableName: String, path: String): Unit=
    df.write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .format("orc")
      .partitionBy("year","month","day")
      .option("path", path)
      .saveAsTable(tableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here using Hive Integration but can be Spark only catalog, a complete example:

1) Need to set up table

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = spark.range(9).map(x => (x, (x + 100) % 3)).toDF("c1", "c2")
df.repartition($"c2")
  .write
  .partitionBy("c2")
  .mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("tabX")
```

2) Update a partition - contrived, in this way after setup

```
val df2 = spark.range(1).map(x => (x, (x + 100) % 3)).toDF("c1", "c2")
df2.repartition($"c2")
   .write
   .mode("overwrite").insertInto("tabX")
```

3) Look at effects:

```
// from 9 -> 7 entries, pls run
val df3 = spark.table("tabX")
df3.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |
+---+---+
|2  |0  |
|5  |0  |
|8  |0  |
|1  |2  |
|4  |2  |
|7  |2  |
|0  |1  |
+---+---+
```

Here is the evidence of partition overwrite, then.

Comment: I always obtain an empty dataframe at the first run. This only works when the table was there before I run the program.

Comment: In fact, my program will create the external table at the first run. But when i add the lines above in my program, the first run will generate an empty external table.

Comment: I will check in a while.

Comment: Posting soon complete example

Comment: thanks!
So there are two main steps to follow. I see that you have first created the table with 'saveAsTable' and then you have updated it with 'insertInto'.
I want this in one shot, in fact. And why cant you user saveAsTable in both 1) and 2)

Comment: It's the only way to do it afaik, I had forgotten that. The fact that no one else has presented a solution may point towards this being a correct statement. The manuals are not well presented on this topic. I see you are in an interesting part of the world.

Comment: Ok I see. Anyway, I will try to adopt your method and dig more for a better way to achieve it.

Comment: This was a feature that was added latterly. If you google like here: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-spark-insertinto-function-1870175c3ee9 you will see the 2 step approach. So I think it is fair to say the answer is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your availability, i will check it and come back to you.